Troubleshooting absence of network connection
After upgrading the operating system on my home server computer from Debian 11 to Debian 12 (by changing sources.list and using apt commands) and then restarting the computer I have no network connection and no IP address. How can I troubleshoot the issue? The computer is a SolidRun Cubox i2eX which uses the  Freescale chip i.MX6 Dual. I'm using a wired connection which works just fine if I plug it into a different computer (and worked just fine during the update). Any clues?
# uname -a                                                  
Linux server 6.1.0-28-armmp #1 SMP Debian 6.1.119-1 (2024-11-22) armv7l GNU/Linux

# ip address                                                
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000                                                                     
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00                       
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo                                              
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever                                  
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute                                      
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever                                  
2: end0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000                                                                           
    link/ether d0:63:b4:00:97:0e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff                          

# lspci
(no output)

In response to requests in the comments,
# dmesg | grep net                                       
[    0.060030] audit: initializing netlink subsys (disabled)                    
[    7.662459] mdio_bus 2188000.ethernet-1: MDIO device at address 4 is missing.
[    7.675076] fec 2188000.ethernet eth0: registered PHC device 0               
[    7.856371] fec 2188000.ethernet end0: renamed from eth0                     

And
# ip link set dev end0 up                                
# ip address                                             
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo                                              
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever                                  
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute                                      
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever                                  
2: end0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000                                                             
    link/ether d0:63:b4:00:97:0e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff                          
    inet6 fe80::d263:b4ff:fe00:970e/64 scope link                               
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever                                  


Your ethernet card is working as seen by the FEC mode changes and the state is up.  Is there some reason your broadcast address is full.  Do you know what your gateway address should be?

Does your network use DHCP, or did you previously need to set a static IP address? Do you know any reason why the ethernet device was renamed from eth0 to end0 and does that affect any configuration you might have previously made for eth0?

@ChrisDavies Thanks for the suggestion. I haven't renamed anything. However, I saw that the file /etc/network/interfaces contained the lines allow-hotplug eth0 and iface eth0 inet dhcp. After replacing eth0 with end0 and rebooting everything seems to be working properly!

I don't know if changing /etc/network/interfaces is the proper solution in this case. Maybe it will be changed back to eth0 by an update?

See Debian Wiki: NetworkInterfaceNames.  You might want to turn off Persistent Naming so that the next update doesn't break it again.

In my case the problem was that the primary network interface was set to eth0 in the file /etc/network/interfaces. Replacing eth0 with end0 and restarting the network service solved the problem.
cp -n /etc/network/interfaces /etc/network/interfaces.orig
sed -i 's/\beth0\b/end0/g' /etc/network/interfaces
systemctl restart network

